# Specify target machine for application deployment cloud foundry

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have a cloud foundry setup with multiple cells(virtual machines) to host the deployed applications.
After 'cf push' the apps get deployed on any of the cell (as per auctioneer algorithm).

Is there a way to define the target VM to host the application?

The production machines should be different from pre-production machines.
How to maintain production and pre-production setup in Cloud Foundry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can assign placement tags on Diego cells and define isolation segments to ensure apps in a space are placed on those specific cells.
That way, you can ensure apps from pre-production and production spaces are hosted on different VMs. Configuration steps are here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/isolation-segments.html.

Comment: I have cf-release v238 which uses CC API Version 2.57.0. The method you suggested requires CF API version 3.0.0+ which is available in later cf-releases. Is there a way to do the same in the current setup? Something similar to isolation segments.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade to use isolation segments, the most straightforward solution is to run two platforms.  One for pre-production and one for productions.  Isolation segments are basically an optimization of this scenario that allows you only to duplicate the parts you want to keep separate, like the gorouters & cells.